# Minimal rank of a real algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, matrix-decomposition, banach-algebras, matrix-rank

Consider a minimal rank of a real algebra generated by real matrices. How can we describe them?

Comment: What's the minimal rank of an algebra?

Comment: It's the smallest nonzero rank of the real algebra generated by real matrices. It's no matter, for an algebra, it can be for a semigroup.

Comment: You described the "minimal rank of an algebra" in terms of the "rank of an algebra", which is not helpful to me.  It seems like what you *mean* to say is that the minimal rank of a real algebra is the least non-zero value of $rk(A)$ over all elements $A$ from the algebra.  Am I interpreting this correctly?

Comment: Also, "How can we describe them" is pretty vague.  What kinds of patterns are we looking for?  Are there any *kinds* of results that you expect?